# iOS User Defaults - do I need to use setInteger:forKey: if I intend to retrieve primitives from defaults using integerForKey:?

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, nsuserdefaults

I'm trying to unpack a dictionary and store it in user defaults. The dictionary contains both strings and numbers/bools.

In my use case, I'm retrieving numbers using `intergerForKey:` and `boolForKey:`
For this use case, **Do I need to store numbers in user defaults using setInteger:forKey: , or can I use generic setObject:forKey: and give it a number*?**

```
    - (void)configureWithJSON:(NSDictionary *)conf {

        NSUserDefaults *defaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];

        NSNumber *timeout = (NSNumber *)conf[@"timeout"];
        if(timeout != nil) {
            [defaults setInteger:[timeout intValue] forKey:@"timeout"];
        }

    //OR

     [defaults setObject:timeout forKey:@"timeout"];

    }


//then, in code I use
 [defaults boolForKey:@"timeout"]?
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the end, it does not matter, both will work. Then the readability kicks in, and `setInteger` does  express the intention more clearly than `setObject` does.

Answer (score 1):

You can add the numbers and bools in NSNumber class and save it in defaults as object.

```
[defaults setObject:[NSNumber numberWithInt:intValue] forKey:@"timeout"];
```

Or

```
[defaults setObject:[NSNumber numberWithBool:boolValue] forKey:@"timeout"];
```

Answer (score 1):

Are you sure your dictionary contains integers and booleans? Afaik dictionaries can only contain objects. That means NSNumber objects representing bools or integers. Aparently you receive an NSNumber object.

You can save the NSNumber objects directly along with all the other properties without diverting via setInterger. There is no sense in converting the NSNumber to int or bool respectively and converting them back to NSNumber later when you fetch them from the properties storage.

Short: 
Go for

```
 [defaults setObject:timeout forKey:@"timeout"];
```

Comment: What I meant is that the JSON file that the dictionary is based on has integers and booleans. The dictionary itself would have them wrapped in objects. I was interested if I need to explicitly unwrap them before storing.